# VIS.JS how to export node color to json file

Tags: javascript, vis.js

Now I can get the position for the network but when I update node `nodes.update({id: idnode2, color: "#f691b2"});`
the current network color that show was changed, but when I export it I only get the position.

So, how can I get all of the updated nodes?

```
function exportNetwork() {
    var nodes = objectToArray(network.getPositions());

    nodes.forEach(addContextualInformation);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        url: 'http://localhost/save_json.php',
        data: {
            data: JSON.stringify(nodes, undefined, 2)
        },
        success: function() {
            alert("Thanks!");
        },
        failure: function() {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    });
}
```